# How to test if the user has selected certain columns

Tags: excel, vba, select

I would like to insert an if condition, to check the selected area is from Columns A to L

This is my code:

```
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Archiv").Range("A" & Sheets("Archiv").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Offset(1)

Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

The problem is the user can select one column, but I need to ensure they have selected column A to L

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Const MSG As String = "Please select a continuous range from ColA to ColM"
    
    If TypeOf Selection Is Range Then  'make sure a range is selected...
        With Selection
            If .Areas.Count = 1 Then   'must be a single area
                If .Cells(1).Column = 1 And .Columns.Count = 12 Then 'A to M
                    'good to go...
                Else
                    MsgBox MSG
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox MSG
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```